# How to iterate through own made xhtml nodes with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, iteration, nodes

I have an ajax handler that gets pieces of pages in parts like:

```
<load loadloc="list" method="append" animation="fadein" >
      <li>add something to a list</li>
</load>
<load loadloc="thediv">
      <h1>hello there</h1>
      <p>this is a paragraph</p>
</load>
<load loadloc="theotherdiv">
      <img src="url.com" />
</load>
```

It iterates over the load elements with `$(htmlfromajax).filter(function(){ do stuf here });`

It works great but when php puts in an error, or I myself put in some other html it tries to iterate over every single line or it just doesn't work. (in js I can't write on multiple lines but when receiving the ajax I get multiple lines so)

```
some php error here
<load loadloc="list" method="append" animation="fadein" >
      <li>add something to a list</li>
</load>
<load loadloc="thediv">
      <h1>hello there</h1>
      <p>this is a paragraph</p>
</load>
<load loadloc="theotherdiv">
      <img src="url.com" />
</load>
```

[A simple example of my ajax handler](http://jsfiddle.net/botenvouwer/XC5Kc/)

How can I use jquery or ajax to only iterate over the load elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your response like it is, try using

```
...
$('<div/>').html(data).find('load').each(function(i, el) {
    // get the load location
    var location = $(el).attr("loadloc");
...
```

instead of

```
...
$(data).filter(function(){
...
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XC5Kc/2/

Comment: This looks like the best way to handle my problem, but why the `'<div/>'`?

Comment: This is just used as a "tool" to throw the html in there and being able to use all the dom methods. If `data` is not a string, but a dom node already, you may skip that part, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to change response to comply valid XML structure in case there was an error. For example wrap the message in `<error>` tag:

```
<error>sometinhg here</error><load>this</load><load><h1>and this</h1></load>
```

Then you can filter only `load` elements:

```
$(data).filter('load').each(function() { ... });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XC5Kc/1/